# Heat pump stops operating too early

Tags: pump, heat, winter

We have an Amana heat pump model ASZ140301. According to the manufacturers specs it's supposed to provide heat down to minus 5 celsius. I was installed about 4 years ago but has never run when the temperature drops below 0 celsius, about 29-30 F.  There is a thermostat on the outdoor unit which is set to about 28F. Is this the problem or part of the problem? The unit is guaranteed for 10 years and the company which did the installation provided a 5 year labor guarantee. Should I call them and try to find out whats going on? We;re in Montreal where winter temps often drop below minus 10 celsius.

Comment: Yes, call them. The fact that it doesn't run below a certain temp, rather than running and not providing enough heat, suggests it's hitting some kind of limit switch.

Comment: `Should I call them and try to find out whats going on?` ... why are you asking this on the internet? ... what if someone says `no`? ... I'm sorry if this comes across as rude, please don't ask other people to tell you what you should be thinking ... if something does not work as expected, then get it fixed

Answer (score 1):

Curious as to why you'd wait four years to investigate. The outdoor  thermostat on the unit looks amazing suspicious. It's probably too late to try adjusting,lowering,the thermostat yourself and experimenting so yes, call the company that did the install so you don't loose the 5 year labor guarantee.